# iOS OTA install not registering custom URL scheme

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ota

For one of our clients, we have developed an OTA app store for distribution.

To enable testing if the apps are installed, in each of the apps I wrote, I added two custom URL schemes: one that's just the app id, and one with the app id and the version (both with `.` replaced by `-`); so for example `com-mycompany-app` and `com-mycompany-app-1-2-0` for com.mycompany.app, version 1.2.0.

Then, in our "app store" I just use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenUrl:]` to determine if an App is installed or the latest version, and if so, replace the "Install" button with an "Open" button.

When installing the  app through XCode, it works great. However, when I install the same app OTA, through my "app store", the `canOpenUrl:` call always returns NO. To see if it was a caching thing, I have tried restarting the "app store" app after OTA install has finished, but I get the same results.

Is this an issue with my manifest plist file? In the Info.plist that belongs to the target, the custom URL Scheme stuff is obviously there, but it's not in the manifest's. However, I would imagine it only uses the manifest to launch initial install...shouldn't the Info.plist be used during actual install to register these sorts of things?  Is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks!

---

Edit: I'm using a custom build script to actually create the `.ipa` and `.plist` files that are being used for OTA distribution. I tried using `iPhone Configuration Utility` to install the IPA directly, and my app store was able to recognize those URLs as being openable. The only possible things I can think of are either that the plist I'm using to download & install needs to have some sort of reference to these custom URL schemes, or it's actually a legitimate bug in Apple's OTA framework.

Comment: have you verified in your custom build script where you generate the .plist that it actually includes the custom schemes?

Comment: Yeah, just to be thorough I added all of the URL scheme stuff to the manifest plist as well. Same results.

Comment: I just tried to archive in XCode, and used the enterprise distribution step as well. I manually placed it on my app store server, and am getting the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working, in case anyone is watching this or stumbles upon a similar issue.

The *only* thing I changed -- and there's no documentation saying the old way wouldn't or shouldn't work -- was to use periods in my URL scheme, instead of hyphens.  So `com-company-app://` became `com.company.app://` (same as the bundle ID), and likewise with the version-appended one.

I don't know if my old URL schemes were violating official URL spec, or if you're supposed to use reverse-DNS, but everything is working, now.